# Templated Insert at End Function

Tags: c++, class, function, templates, insert

I am trying to create a templated function that will insert a value at the end of an array, however I keep running into a seg fault no matter what I try to do. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
template <typename T> 
void ArrayList<T>::insert_back(const T& x)
{
   if(m_size == m_max)
   {
      m_max = m_max*2; //resize array
      T* P = new T[m_max];
      for(int y = 0; y < m_size; y++) //copying array
      {
         P[y] = m_data[y];
      }
      delete[] m_data; //copy done delete
      m_data = P;
      P[m_size] = x; //gdb segfault -- caused by accessing P[m_size]
      m_size ++;
   }
   else // no resizing
   {
     m_data[m_size] = x;
     m_size++;
   }
}
```

Comment: What are `m_size`, `m_max` and `m_data` initialized to?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted works, given that you've correctly initialized `m_data`, `m_size` and `m_max`. In fact, I created a test version [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/37kJFT%245) and it runs without errors. For simplicitly, I placed it in a struct, this was only to make it easier for me to write. Also, I changed your loop variable to size_t, to avoid warnings about comparing signed and unsigned values.

Given this, the most likely issue is that you've not allocated any initial memory. `m_size` should be initialized to zero and `m_max` needs to be greater than zero (and match the amount of allocated memory), otherwise the new computed `m_max` will be `2*m_max` which is still 0.